# How to implement binary search for array of strings?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

I did some research and wasn't able to find anything but if this is a duplicate please let me know.

I have this code for binary search of integers

```
package thepac;

public class CustomBS{

public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] listOfNumbers = new int[]{2,45,65,76,89,100,342,455};
    int numberToSearch = 100;
    int lowestIndex = 0;
    int highestIndex = listOfNumbers.length-1;
    int middleIndex;

    while(lowestIndex<=highestIndex){
        middleIndex = (lowestIndex+highestIndex)/2;

        if(numberToSearch > listOfNumbers[middleIndex]){
            lowestIndex = middleIndex+1;
        }else if(numberToSearch < listOfNumbers[middleIndex]){
            highestIndex = middleIndex-1;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }//end of while
    if(lowestIndex > highestIndex){
        System.out.println("not found");
    }else{
        System.out.println("found");
    }
}
}
```

This works just find and I understand the concept. Is it possible to implement a version of this that searches for Strings as in an array of Strings?

I can't think of how to implement this since the current algorithm checks if the number being searched is higher or lower than the middle index, but if it's a String, how do I check if it's higher or lower than another string?

I know I can use the String.compareTo() method to check if a string is larger or shorter than another one but I'm not sure if this would be the correct way of implementing this.

Comment: you mean... like [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-)?

Comment: Thanks - I'm familiar with that method but I want to implement my own algorithm that does binary search on Strings. I can't see the internal implementation of the method you suggested.

Comment: yes, you can use `String.compareTo()` method if you want to write your own implementation.

Comment: Would you have an example of how to use it in such implementation?

Comment: @pgonzaleznetwork the code of the java API is open source. You should be able to look it up under `path/to/JDK/src.zip`. You can find some examples [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_binarysearch_int.htm), [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/binarysearch-java), [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/java/using-the-java-arrays-binary-search-methods.html),...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have two strings `s1` and `s2` then

```
s1.compareTo(s2)
```

returns a negative result if `s1` is lexicographically smaller than `s2`, a positive result if `s1` is lexicographically bigger than `s2` and 0 if they are equal.

So you can write your function like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] listOfStrings = new String[]{"a","b","c","d","g","h","k","z"};
    String stringToFind = "d";
    int lowestIndex = 0;
    int highestIndex = listOfStrings.length-1;
    int middleIndex = 0;

    while(lowestIndex<=highestIndex){
        middleIndex = (lowestIndex+highestIndex)/2;

        if(stringToFind.compareTo(listOfStrings[middleIndex]) > 0){
            lowestIndex = middleIndex+1;
        }else if(stringToFind.compareTo(listOfStrings[middleIndex]) < 0){
            highestIndex = middleIndex - 1;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }//end of while
    if(lowestIndex > highestIndex){
        System.out.println("not found");
    }else{
        System.out.println("found at " + middleIndex);
    }
}
```